# Signing Page Customisation

Tags: ios, docusignapi

I am customising my signing page but cannot find any way to change the background colour and text of buttons such as 'Select Style', 'Clear', 'Draw' in signature adoption page. I understand that we can change the colours and add logo from the DocuSign Admin console and worked for other buttons and headers in the signing page but not with these above mentioned buttons in adoption page. Help!!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please upvote all useful answers, including those to others' questions. Also, please "check" the best answer to your own questions.

Answer (score 1):

For customizing the web signing experience, please see the [Signing Resource File guide](https://www.docusign.com/supportdocs/pdf/docusign-signing-resource-file(v1.1).pdf).

If you're using a WebView resource for an iOS app, then I think the resource file will also apply.

You can change button text. If you do so, then you should also change the text appropriately for all of the languages (DocuSign supports 43 languages for signing).